# Does Identity Platform Multitenancy not support authentication via phone number?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I'm experiencing difficulties implementing phone number authentication with the Identity Platform under a multi-tenant setup. When I specify a tenant from the Identity Platform dashboard, I seem unable to add the phone as a provider. Does this mean it's impossible to set up a phone number-based login?

For context, I've reviewed the following in the documentation:
[https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy?hl=en#supported_sign-in_methods](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy#supported_sign-in_methods)

Should I consider switching to a different service? Currently, I'm using Cognito, but its specifications are somewhat complex, and Auth0 is prohibitively expensive. If there are any better alternatives, I'd be grateful for your recommendations.

For sign up:

1. The user submits their phone number.
2. The user receives a confirmation code via SMS.
3. The user inputs the received confirmation code to complete account creation.

For login:

1. The user submits their phone number.
2. The user receives a confirmation code via SMS.
3. The user inputs the received confirmation code to log in.

In the worst-case scenario, I'd be okay with setting up phone number accounts using the Admin API on the server side, as long as this allows users to log in afterward.

Comment: Cloud Identity platform is agnostic to how the user authenticate when you use federation. It's the identity provider that tells our Identity Platform is the user authentication have been successful. So you will have to check on the side of Cognito

Comment: They haven't done it yet, been waiting for a while. GCP is quite frustrating with its unresponsiveness. Add +1 here and pray: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268476475